# Android Retrofit and JWT authentication

Tags: android, jwt, retrofit2

I am using JWT authentication and storing the auth token in the shared preference. I am not able to find a way to add authorization header to the retrofit client . That's why I am getting 401 errors for my network call the first time , from the second time it works. How to solve it ?

```
@Module
public class AppRetrofitModule {


private static final String TAG = "AppRetrofitModule";

private static Retrofit.Builder builder
        = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Config.REST_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()).build();

private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient
        = new OkHttpClient.Builder();


private static HttpLoggingInterceptor logging
        = new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);


@Singleton
@Provides
public Retrofit provideRetrofit(AppPreferencesHelper appPreferencesHelper) {


    String authToken = "Bearer " + appPreferencesHelper.getAccessToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "provideRetrofit: " + authToken);


    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            Response response = chain.proceed(original);


            Request request = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", authToken)
                    .method(original.method(), original.body()).build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

   if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(logging)) {
       httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        httpClient.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.callTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        builder.client(httpClient.build());
        retrofit = builder.build();
    }

    return retrofit;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            Response response = chain.proceed(original);
     String authToken = "Bearer " + appPreferencesHelper.getAccessToken();
 

            Request request = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", authToken)
                    .method(original.method(), original.body()).build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

   if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(logging)) {
       httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        httpClient.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.callTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        builder.client(httpClient.build());
        retrofit = builder.build();
    }

    return retrofit;
```

Previously I was making the mistake of getting the authToken outside the interceptor. But it needs to be fetched inside the interceptor such that we can get the token at the first time too. It was working before for the second API call because the authToken value gets refreshed.